# How to pass KeychainGroup to a GraphClient, in C#

Tags: ios, maui, microsoft-graph-booking

I have a .NET8 MAUI project, where I initialize a graph client like this:

```
    private static readonly string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    private static readonly string tenantId = "tenant";
    private static readonly string clientId = "client";
    private static readonly TokenCredentialOptions options = new TokenCredentialOptions {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    };
    private static readonly UsernamePasswordCredential credential = new UsernamePasswordCredential("username", "password", tenantId, clientId, options);
    private static readonly GraphServiceClient graph = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);
```

In the same file where I init this client, I am making a call through the client, like this:

```
 res = await graph.Solutions.BookingBusinesses["bookings@bookingsample.com"].Appointments.GetAsync();
```

Running this on an Android device produces the expected outcome, and 'res' is populated with data. However, on iOS, I get the following error:
[image: A screenshot of an error message, detailing the question.]
In my Entitlements.plist, I have added the string "XXXXX.com.microsoft.adalcache".

**How do I pass WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup to the graph client?**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! At first, I just used $(AppIdentifierPrefix).com.microsoft.adalcache, but when I manually inserted the identifier, with the rest of the string, it worked. I didn't need to add .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup.

Comment: Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.